# How to launch remote windows desktop from asp.net web application

Tags: .net

Can anyone please suggest how to launch remote windows desktop in asp.net web application using html5 canvas tag and websockets.

Comment: What did you try already ? Could you be more precise ? Do you want t launche the RDP cient on the cient computer or provide them with one in their browsers ? In the first case : did you check this MS Resurce explaining how t create an rdp file ? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731192.aspx you just have to serve the file you built to your users

Comment: My requirement is that the customer will login into our URL and via our URL he will be provided a list of servers he has privilege to, when he clicks  on a particular system name, then that system has to open up within our URL. He should be able to do all the activities in that system.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille), an HTTP to RDP gateway written in C# for .NET. Basically, it provides access to windows hosted remote desktops from a web browser, using HTML5 canvas and websockets. It also works with HTML4 browsers, using divs and ajax.